# Does the word 'austerity'make sense

Tags: single-word-requests, sentence

i came across this word- 'austerity' and I wanted to know whether it made sense in this sentence.

W.H. Auden’s Refugee Blues laments the plight of Jews in the years before World War 2 while suggesting the **austerity** and antagonism they faced when seeking asylum in the democracies of the period.

Also, if the sentence can be improved, can you tell me how.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The Oxford Dictionary defines [austerity](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/austerity) as:

> Sternness or severity of manner or attitude.

This well describes the attitude of the consul:

> > The consul banged the table and said,
>
> "If you've got no passport you're officially dead":
>
> But we are still alive, my dear, but we are still alive.
>
> > Came to a public meeting; the speaker got up and said;
>
> "If we let them in, they will steal our daily bread":
>
> He was talking of you and me, my dear, he was talking of you and me.

The consul was not hostile, he was indifferent and uncaring, his manner was austere.

Another meaning of austerity, the state of being austere, is given in the definition for [austere:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/austere)

> (of living conditions or a way of life) having no comforts or luxuries

which also describes the plight of the refugees.

> > Say this city has ten million souls,
>
> Some are living in mansions, some are living in holes:
>
> Yet there's no place for us, my dear, yet there's no place for us.

Comment: So, is my sentence alright?

Comment: Yes.  Your sentence is good.